# after_create does not create changes in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use a `after_create` call back to calculate the penalty of a submitted `HomeworkDocument`, based on the deadline of the `Assignment` that `HomeworkDocument` `belongs_to`.

```
  class HomeworkDocument < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :calculate_penalty
  private

    def calculate_penalty
      time_late = created_at - assignment.deadline
      case
      when time_late < 0
        self.penalty = 0
      when time_late > 1.day
        self.penalty = 1
      end
    end
```

Everything works fine in my spec as well as when I create `HomeworkDocument` one at a time in the console. However, when using loop (e.g. to populate sample data), the call back seems to be bypassed as all of the homework documents have `penalty: nil`.

The loop is very straightforward:

```
   Student.all.each do |student|
      Assignment.all.each do |assignment|
        student.submitted_homework_documents.create(
          assignment_id: assignment.id,
          created_at: rand(-1.month..1.month).ago)
      end
   end
```

Is this expected? If so, how do I create my sample data with the `after_create` call back properly applied?

Comment: You have to call `.save` in order to persist the changes in the database (in your `calculate_penalty` callback)

Comment: You are absolutely right. It turns out that my spec was wrong -- I forgot to reload the homework variable from the database. If you make this an answer I'll pick it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to a add a call to `save` the instance of the `HomeworkDocument`, so use `self.save`.

```
def calculate_penalty
  time_late = created_at - assignment.deadline
  case
  when time_late < 0
    self.penalty = 0
  when time_late > 1.day
    self.penalty = 1
  end
  self.save
end
```